# formGroup expects a FormGroup instance - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms

I need to get all the form values on submit. The code is as follows.

html file

```
<form id="cloneInfo" *ngIf="selectedAccount" [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="cloneRecord()">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="staticEmail">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Account Id</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="accountRefId">
        </div>
      </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Component file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';       
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-list',
  templateUrl: './account-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-list.component.scss'],
  providers: [UtilsService]
   })

export class AccountListComponent implements OnInit {
  todo: FormGroup;
 constructor(private utilsService: UtilsService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
    this.getAccounts();
 }

 cloneRecord() {
    console.log(this.todo.value)
 }

}
```

But i am getting the following error

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

enter code here
```

Is there anything wrong in the code? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to initialize a todo?

```
constructor(private utilsService: UtilsService,
private fb: FormBuilder
) {}

this.todo = this.fb.group({
control: ['initialValue', [Validators.required]]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have `formControlName` in your input. Second, you have to initialize todo by `FormBuilder` or manually, [this](http://learnangular2.com/forms/) is very helpful.